# How to create this Android View/Layout

Tags: android, view

I'm working on my first Android application and I have a pretty good idea of what I want my application to look like, I'm just not sure how to create the view.

I have a Listview with several items, I then want users to click on an item then get a detail page. I want my detail page to look like this.

[image: view example]

I know how to get the background. What I'm trying to figure out is what's the best way to create that rounded, see-through table with a border. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way would be to create a linear layout with vertical orientation and define a drawable [shape](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Shape) resource and set the corners to have a radius to match what you like. Then add your 2 text views and an image view and lines for the separators.

Comment: Wait, what do you mean lines for seperators?

Comment: The horizontal grey bars you have dividing your text views from each other. I do not believe that that is built into the LinearLayout. You'll have to create drawable resource (images or shapes) to represent those too.